# Is there any Deobandi sheikh clamid to meet the prophet in person?

Tags: prophet-muhammad, islamic-philosophy, hanafi, sufism

I've been watching Uthman Ibn Farooq dabate. He stated that there are some sects of Deobandies that believe the prophet Muhammad(swa) is physically alive and is meeting their sheikhs in person and even having dinner with them. ([here is the link](https://youtu.be/JUK_SRnRV7A?t=2052))

Is this true? What are some examples of Deobandi sheikhs that claimed to be visited by the prophet Muhammad(swa) in person?

Comment: Why somebody downvoted me? It is a very legitimate question!

Answer (score 0):

Neither Sunni, nor 12er Shia, nor 5er Shia, and not even Ahmaddya or Bahai say or said that Muhammad (p.b.u.h) is physically alive.

Furthermore, we are requested to have and keep a direct relation to God Allah. We should not pray to Muhammad (p.b.u.h) or take him as an intermediate in our prayers.

This sect is for sure not in line with all major sects of Islam. We may let them go or try to discuss but we do well not to believe them.

Deobandi are a Sunni movement with a political engagement. As to Information I could find, they do not uphold such teachings but they are open to discuss with anyone.